# Lag between Spring @Transaction finish and actual DB commit

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a simple  SpringBoot application, which is using SpringData and has the next structure
SlotConfigsController -> Repository (CrudRepository)

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConfigsController {
    private final ConfigsRepository configsRepository;

    @PostMapping(path = "/configs")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> saveConfig(@RequestBody ConfigDto config) {
        ConfigEntity config = CONFIGS_MAPPER.dtoToEntity(config);
        configsRepository.save(config);
        log.info("Transactional method finished");
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigsRepository extends CrudRepository<ConfigsEntity, Long> {
    @Transactional
    ConfigsEntity save(ConfigsEntity entity);
}
```

I started Postgres DB using docker-compose and enabled logs via

```
environment:
      - EXTRA_CONF=log_statement=all
```

---

What I noticed during the log analysis is that the actual DB commit (inside the docker log) occurs after the `log.info(...)` call.
Here is the log from the code

```
17:12:11,856 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [TransactionSynchronizationManager.java] - Clearing transaction synchronization 
17:12:11,856 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [TransactionSynchronizationManager.java] - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@550de51c] for key [HikariDataSource (Hikari)] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
17:12:11,856 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [TransactionSynchronizationManager.java] - Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@6752dcc] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(java.lang.Object)] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
17:12:11,857  INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [SlotConfigsController.java] - Transactional method finished
17:12:11,863 TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [TransactionSynchronizationManager.java] - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@4ecd9132] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@2210e466] from thread [http-nio-8080-exec-2]
```

And here is the docker DB log

```
17:12:11.871 UTC [555] test@test LOG: execute <unnamed>: update public.slot_configs set close_time=$1 where slot_config_id=$2
17:12:11.871 UTC [555] test@test DETAIL: parameters: $1 = '1630', $2 = 5
17:12:11.877 UTC [555] test@test LOG: execute S_2: COMMIT
```

At 17:12:11,**857** we exited the Transactional `CrudRepository.save` method, but the real data insertion in the DB and transaction commit happens only at 17:12:11.**871** -  17:12:11.**877**

I supposed, that when the `@Transactional` method will be finished, data should be already in the DB, but looks like this action is asynchronous.
I was also trying to create a Service between controller and repository and mark the save method in the service as `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`, but it doesn't change anything. There is still a lag between code transactions and actual transactions in the DB.

Why does it happen? And is it possible to say Spring to wait for the DB transaction commit before exiting the `@Transactional` method?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The transaction will commit after the `@Transactional` has ended. That is your transactional boundary. What basically happens is **transaction start** -> **execute service method** -> **transaction commit**. No commit somewhere in between your methods in your service call. So it works as designed. So the commit occurs **after** the call to `log.info`.

Comment: There is no any `@Transactional` annotation within the controller. Only save method is marked as `@Transactional`.
So after the `save` method finished we're already out of our transaction and we went to the next line of code `log.info`
Let me edit the classes, so it'll be more clear.

Comment: Also another thing is you are syncing on timestamps, if those clocks don't match you are not going to have a matching timeline anyway. Matching/correlating logs on timestamps is problematic imho (and experience). The `@Transactional` on the `save` doesn't add anything that de default `save` method already does.  Finally disable open-session-in-view as that might influence things as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thank you, I've added the `@Transactional` on the save method just for clarity (I understand that it's not affect anything).
Regarding the disabled open-session-in-view - thank you! I didn't know about it, checking now.
Btw, in case if timestamps are not recommended way, maybe are there are suggestions from your side?

Comment: If there is an, ever so slight, drift between clocks or whatever than your logging will be off. You want to include a span etc. something like what OpenTrace/Zipkin provides.